# UITableViewCell textLabel offset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to have my text in my UITableViewCell to be a little bit to the right. In other words I want to have an x-offset. Is this even possble? Do I have to create a custom cell just because of this?

Comment: a simple thing you can do is add few spaces before the text. may be this can help you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try this :

```
[cell setIndentationLevel:SOME_NUMBER];
[cell setIndentationWidth:SOME_OTHER_NUMBER];
```

Comment: You should add subviews to the cell's contentView, not directly in the cell itself.

Comment: this doesn't work as well,as what it does it covers up the textLabel.text

Comment: While this solution idea is a good one (adding a custom label), the code sample isn't very good. First, @Mike Weller is correct, subview should be added to `cell.contentView`. Second, the new label should be added inside the `if (cell == nil)` check so you don't add labels to dequeued cell instanced that already have them. Set a tag on the label so you can then retrieve it after the cell has been obtained so you can set the text.

Comment: You shouldn't discuss the code rather than discussing people, like you did with Mike Weller. If his point is not valid then discuss his comment.

Answer (score 112):

You could use `cell.indentationLevel` and if needed `cell.indentationWidth` instead of custom UITableViewCell for this.

Comment: This is the best answer, why isn't this marked as the solution? It's exactly what the guy was asking for.

Comment: The best solution for a vanilla cell.

Comment: `Amount of indentation` = `cell.indentationLevel (default 0)` * `cell.indentationWidth (default 10.0 points)`. FYI.

Answer (score 12):

A simple solution is you can change the frame of the textLabel.

```
CGRect textLabelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
textLabelFrame.origin.x += xOffset;
textLabelFrame.size.width -= xOffset;
cell.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
```

I've also done this by creating a custom UILabel that supports edgeInsets similar to a UIButton. This is a better solution b/c you can layout the label to correct size but the above will work if you have simple needs.

[EDIT 1/2: fixed typo w/ CGRect]

[EDIT 3: fixed typo setting modified frame]

[EDIT 4: need a simple subclass]

Mea culpa. I was wrong that you can do this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The UITableViewCell layout happens after the tableView delegate/datasource has a chance to customize the cell. I've tested the implementation below, it works.

Do as I say above but create a (simple) subclass of `UITableViewCell` that adds the `xOffset` in `layoutSubviews`. If you do this, you can also add an `xOffset` property that you can set in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
@implementation XOffsetCell
// assumes property xOffset is defined and synthesized
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect textLabelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
    textLabelFrame.origin.x += self.xOffset;
    textLabelFrame.size.width -= self.xOffset;
    cell.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
}
@end
```

The solution that suggested adding a custom `UILabel` to `cell.contentView` is also a good solution. I saw your comment that it obscures the built-in `textLabel` but that's the whole point. You would not use the built-in label anymore, use the custom label instead.

Comment: you mean UIRectFrame? There is no CGRectFrame

Comment: sprry, typing too fast. meant CGRect.

Comment: yes, but that's really no big deal. subclassing objects is extremely common and easy. this is also a very simple subclass.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not trolling for votes, but wanted to show what the code provided by @iPhone monster "should" look like. His solution is a valid option. If you add the label to the cell after the `if (cell == nil)` as he did you will be continually adding labels to dequeued cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f, 10.0f, 150.0f, 20.0f)];
        lbl.tag = OffsetLabelTag; // define this as a constant
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
        [lbl release];
    }

    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:OffsetLabelTag];
    [lbl setText:@"test text"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: true... but I would like to use the value of the text stored at this label at the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I guess this is not possible then?

Comment: you can access the label the same way I did here. Anywhere you have access to the cell, you have access to the custom label by using `[cell.contentView viewWIthTag:OffsetLabelTag]`. I would also consider whether you really need to get a value from the label here. If possible, it's better to get whatever value you need from your data model.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with Autolayouts:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell new];
cell.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(indentation)-[textLabel]-(indentation)-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:@{@"indentation": @35}
                                                                           views:@{@"textLabel": cell.textLabel}]];
```

Or using [Parus lib](https://github.com/DAlOG/Parus):

```
[cell.contentView addConstraints:(PVVFL(@"H:|-(indentation)-[textLabel]-(indentation)-|")
                                  .withViews(@{@"textLabel": textLabel})
                                  .metrics(@{@"indentation": @35}).asArray)];
```

Comment: This is quite a neat solution that seems to work initially. However, I found that when you scrolled around the indentation seemed to vanish as cells went out of view and then back in again

Comment: @andygeers seems like you lack of other constraints. Once you define ```.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;``` it is your responsibility to put all necessary constraints, so view position will be well defined for auto layout system. In this case you need also specify vertical constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Other way:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return intOffset;  // but is like '\t', not points
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another not very pretty and smart way : ) Position of Label in TableViewCell depends on size of image assigned to cell.imageView.image property. So if you want your text to move right you can add several blank pixel columns to image in cell.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5659826/1058199, here is a Swift version.

This works within the cell to ONLY move the textLabel to the right. Swift 5.4

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var textLabelFrame = self.textLabel?.frame
    textLabelFrame?.origin.x += 32
    textLabelFrame?.size.width -= 32
    self.textLabel?.frame = textLabelFrame ?? CGRect.zero
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Will `cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` be enough for you. It could align the text to the center creating that space for you

Comment: It is too centered... I want it to be more to the left... just like a tab

Comment: Custom cell would work but can you try to add a label to the cell's view. You can adjust the frame of this label.

Comment: Create UILabel and add it the cell's view by [cell.contentView addSubview:yourLabel];